# How to display text on Tilemaps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I'm developing a hexagonal tilemap game. Every tilemap is a player and I need to display their scores on them. How can I do this?

Comment: Using a TextMeshPro object?

Comment: Yes, but how can i use an object in a Tilemap?

Comment: If you found a solution, @LeventAkdağ , could share your code? I'm also stuck on how to instantiate text in each tile.

Comment: @leila-m I found a solution , I am instantiating text objects to a canva by converting tiles positions to real world position. It is something like this: `scorePrefabArray[players[i].x , players[i].y ] = Instantiate(score, tMap.CellToWorld(new Vector3Int((players[i].x ), (players[i].y ), 0)), Quaternion.identity, canva.transform) as GameObject;
            scorePrefabArray[players[i].x , players[i].y ].GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI>().text = (scoreArray[(players[i].x ), (players[i].y )]).ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a prefab with your text setup (e.g. a worldspace [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html) object), and then instantiate them using [`Tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld.html) to get the appropriate positioning for relevant tiles. Get the text object using `GetComponent<TextMeshPro>()` so you can change the text etc.